# Const Correctness - Const Pointer As Function Argument

Tags: c++, c

consider a function like

```
char* strcpy (char* destination, const char* source);
```

The given value at (address) source is const because the author of the function wants to show that the value of source will not be changed by strcpy. The pointer itself is not changed by strcpy to. Why not to write

```
char* strcpy (char* destination, const char* const source);
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pointer itself is passed by value, so there's no point.

Answer (score 2):

It could as well be written like that, but it wouldn't affect the caller in any case.

In the second case the prototype says that the pointer itself should not be modified, but the caller's pointer cannot be modified anyway, because it is copied (passed by value) when calling the function.

Marking variables passed by value with `const` is useful only to the implementer of the function as a way to make his intents clear.

Answer (score 0):

You will see if you try to implement both functions, that they are actually the same. A `const` modifier at that point is only meaningful to the body of the function, since the argument is passed by value anyway.

```
error: function "strcpy" has already been defined
char* strcpy (char* destination, const char* const source)
```

Comment: What happens if I set source within the function body to NULL after I delivered the pointer to destination?

Comment: The local copy `source` used as the function argument would be set to `NULL`, not the argument that was passed to it.